# rename columns in R using str_replace_all for more than two string types

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, stringr

I have a dataset (dataraw) with column labels such as

condition1_men, condition1_women, condition2_men, condition3_women (etc)

I want to replace the strings 'condition1', 'condition2' with their names.

**condition1**_women = **related**_women;

**condition2**_men = **unrelated**_men;

**condition3**_men = **filler**_men;

Current code:

```
data <- dataraw %>%
 rename_all(~ str_replace_all(str_replace(., 'condition1', "related"), 'condition2', "unrelated"))
```

This is working for up to 2 strings, every way I attempt to add a third string, I get unexpected symbol errors.

```
 data <- dataraw %>%
rename_all(~ str_replace_all(str_replace((., 'condition1', "related"), 'condition2', "unrelated"), 'condition3', "filler")))
```

I'm sure this must be simple, but no matter the combinations I try I'm getting errors.
Would anyone be able to point me towards the simple mistake I'm making?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to pass both `pattern` and `replacement` as vectors when you want to do multiple replacements (or define a function).  Details are in the online doc.  Alternatively, you could `pivot_longer`, manipulate and `pivot_wider`.  Or (my preferred option), simply `pivot_longer` to make your data frame [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rename_all` was superseded over 6 years ago in favor of `rename_with`, I'll use that:

```r
library(dplyr)
dataraw <- data.frame(condition1_men=1, condition1_women=2, condition2_men=3, condition2_women=4, condition3_men=5)
dataraw
#   condition1_men condition1_women condition2_men condition2_women condition3_men
# 1              1                2              3                4              5
dataraw |>
  rename_with(.fn = ~ sub("^condition1_", "related_", sub("^condition2_", "unrelated_", .)))
#   related_men related_women unrelated_men unrelated_women condition3_men
# 1           1             2             3               4              5
```

If you have a (named) vector of "from=to" assignments, we can also do it like this to be a little more general:

```r
conds <- c(condition1="related", condition2="unrelated")
dataraw |>
  rename_with(.fn = ~ Reduce(function(st, i) sub(names(conds)[i], conds[i], st), seq_along(conds), init = .x))
#   related_men related_women unrelated_men unrelated_women condition3_men
# 1           1             2             3               4              5
```

We need `Reduce` since we need to preserve all changes from previous condition mappings.

I often find data like this does better (in later data-munging/analysis) in a long format (as Limey suggested). For that, we can also do:

```r
dataraw |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
                      names_to = c("cond", ".value")) |>
  mutate(cond2 = conds[match(sub("_.*", "", cond), names(conds))])
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   cond         men women cond2    
#   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
# 1 condition1     1     2 related  
# 2 condition2     3     4 unrelated
# 3 condition3     5    NA NA
```

though it might be simpler (data management, visualizing, updating, etc) if your mapping were in a different frame, which we can merge/join onto the original data:

```r
cond_df <- tribble(
  ~ cond, ~ cond2
  , "condition1", "related"
  , "condition2", "unrelated"
)
dataraw |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
                      names_to = c("cond", ".value")) |>
  left_join(cond_df, by = "cond")
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   cond         men women cond2    
#   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
# 1 condition1     1     2 related  
# 2 condition2     3     4 unrelated
# 3 condition3     5    NA NA
```

Comment: Fantastic - this has done just what I needed. Thank you so much for taking the time to write the clear explanation along with the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The @r2evans' answer is the best. If pivoting is a concern for whatever reason, here´s a possible solution with `colnames()` and `purrr`:

```
dataraw <- tibble(
  condition1_women = c("a", "b", "c"),
  condition2_men   = c("x", "y", "z"),
  condition3_men   = c("i", "j", "k"))

# A tibble: 3 × 3 -------------------
  condition1_women condition2_men condition3_men
  <chr>            <chr>          <chr>         
1 a                x              i             
2 b                y              j             
3 c                z              k

labels <- tribble(
  ~ old, ~ new,
  "condition1", "related",
  "condition2", "unrelated",
  "condition3", "filler")

# A tibble: 3 × 2 -------------------
  old        new      
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 condition1 related  
2 condition2 unrelated
3 condition3 filler 

old_names <- colnames(dataraw)

# -----------------------------------
[1] "condition1_women" "condition2_men"   "condition3_men"  

new_names <- map2_chr(
  labels$old, labels$new,
  \(y, z) modify(
    keep(old_names,\(x) str_detect(x, y)), 
    \(x) str_replace(x, y, z)))

# -----------------------------------   
[1] "related_women" "unrelated_men" "filler_men"

colnames(dataraw) <- new_names

# A tibble: 3 × 3 -------------------
  related_women unrelated_men filler_men
  <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     
1 a             x             i         
2 b             y             j         
3 c             z             k
```